# vb.net datagridview rowfilter issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Currently my datagridview is linked to a textbox, so when the user types in letters it filters the grid.

The grid is linked to a datatable like this:

```
 Grid.DataSource = dtProducts.DefaultView
```

This is procedure for filtering:

```
    'Filter Source Grid according to what user types to textbox
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtProBox.TextChanged
    dtProducts.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[Product] LIKE '*" & txtProBox.Text & "*'"
End Sub
```

This works just fine till i have an accented letter in the textbox.
As you can see in the included screenshot when i type just the first 2 letters of the title "Kígyóuborka" it pops up the results just fine. But whenever i type the third letter which is a "g" the title dissapears.
However after typing the fourth letter which is an "y" in this case, the title pops back again.
It does this weird behaviour with a couple of titles and all i could figure out myself that is has to do something with accented characters.

Did anyone ever encounter this issue?

Thanks :)

[rowfilter isuee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPrOI.jpg)

Comment: Watch out with this code! This is the prototypical way of getting SQL-injection attacks.

Comment: [This site](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/) has a lot of examples how to user RowFilter properly. My first guess is that the first `*` is redundant: `[Product] LIKE '" & txtProBox.Text & "*'"`. As @JochenvanWylick wrote escape the string from your textbox first before use it the RowFilter.

Comment: According to the link you gave me: dataView.RowFilter = "Name LIKE '%jo%'"     // values that contain 'jo'" So my code should just work fine. And how would u avoid the sql injection?

Comment: I think sql injections shouldn't be an issue as this textbox isnt linked with the database itself. It is only linked with the datatable which is just a copy in memory if i got it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
dtProducts.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[Product] LIKE '%" & txtProBox.Text & "%'"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but unfortunately it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: i'm not sure but could you try change & to +

Comment: `%`: filters on products which **contain** the given string. 

`*`: filters on products which **start with** the given string. So depending on your needs you have to choose one of them.

Comment: i tried all possible combination and still the same issue, seems like an unfixable bug..